# Does the exists function have a performance cost in Django's ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

Lets say I am trying to query a table like so:

```
if MyModel.objects.filter(field1='some-value', field2='some-value').exists():
    obj = MyModel.objects.select_related('related_model_1', 'related_model_2').get(field1='some-value', field2='some-value')
else:
    return Response({'detail': 'Not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Am I incurring a performance cost by checking the existence and then selecting the related fields? Or is it small enough to be negligible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will query the database, but the minimum possible query.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

> Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not. **This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query**.

and

> Additionally, if a some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists() **will do more overall work** (one query for the existence check plus an extra one to later retrieve the results) than simply using bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if any were returned.